# Exporting coordinates from LAS files to CSV?

Tags: convert, coordinates, csv, lidar, las

Is there any tool available for extracting the X, Y and Z coordinates from a .las file and exporting them to a .csv or similar file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Are you looking for new software or do you already have GIS software and are just looking for a tool you have not used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

las2txt from liblas.org may do what you want:

http://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2txt.html

Answer (score 2):

Assume the following:

- .las file  = `input.las`.
- `input.las` path: `C:\lidar\input.las`.
- .csv file: `output.csv`.
- `output.csv` path: `C:\lidar\output.csv`.

---

With [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html), the command line to export as CSV is `LDA2ASCII`. Its syntax is:

```
LDA2ASCII InputFile OutputFile format
```

Write the following:

```
C:\Fusion\LDA2ASCII C:\lidar\input.las C:\lidar\output.csv. 0
```

The argument `0` will export only the x, y and z coordinates (use `1` to also export: nadir angle and intensity values). It will create the file `output.csv` in the folder `c:\lidar`.

<sub>In the example above, Fusion was installed under `C:\Fusion`.</sub>

---

With R, there is the `readLAS` function from the `rLiDAR` package, which can be used to import .las files. Then, converting it as CSV is simple.

```r
library(rLiDAR)
rLAS <- readLAS("C:\\lidar\\input.las", short=TRUE) #use short = FALSE to display more columns with data associated to each return. For example: classification code, gps time, etc.
rLAS <- data.frame(rLAS)
head(rLAS,3) #see first three rows

       X       Y      Z Intensity ReturnNumber
732652.6 7459140 31.194        24            1
732652.7 7459141 31.426        58            1
732652.7 7459141 31.253        17            1

write.csv(rLAS,"C:\\lidar\\output.csv")
```